# Best Way to Modify Another Programmer's Navigation

Tags: coding-style

"Change an item in the navigation? Sure I can do that in 15 minutes."

So I am trying to update the navigation on a site that I inherited only to find out that the previous programmer was a college student and was using this site as a project of some sort.  Needless to say there are zero comments and the code calls function after function and I just can't follow the logic.

I am looking for a roundabout way to update the navigation. I tried using Dreamweaver to search through all of the files in the site and look for any files that contain the name of the page or the url (hoping to find some sort of included file). There was none. I did file text files that control the main navigation but none for the subnavigation.

There is no database.

If it helps here is the site. http://bit.ly/jbs639

And if you want to look at the interesting text file that is parsed to create the main navigation you can find it here: http://bit.ly/m3erna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it was as simple as a function that reads all of the files in the directory and the name of the file. I guess that in this case there was no shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.... Interesting indeed. You have my sympathy.

One thing that I would look at... The file that gets parsed for the main navigation appears to be a simple delimited file. Sure, the delimiter is a rather unusual +++, but that choice means it avoids conflict with things like commas that might be desirable in the link text. It looks as if the last element indicates what type of resource is being accessed (file or directory, although I don't know what - if any - effect that has on the final output). It also appears that there are similar text files (in the framework/cfg/nav/ folder... which should probably not be generally accessible BTW) for the sub-menus. (E.g. the file stores.txt appears to contain the additional navigation items associated with the stores sub-navigation).

You don't mention which sub-menu you're trying to change. I suspect it is the "About TTO" one, which I can't find an entry for... but I'd look to see if there are any similar navigation text files in the /content/about/ folder.

Good Luck!

Comment: I am trying to edit the "Shell Fleet Fuel Program" sub menu.

I looked for files containing '+++' and I couldn't find any new text files. I also looked in the /content/about/ directory and didn't find anything.

I had previously found out that there actually is a system set up to process the submenus and if the developer used that system (as he did for the stores page) this would be easy. But I think that between the various web developers working on this site that there were some hacks put in and this is one of them.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately not ones that I can see "from the outside". My next step would be to look at /content/fleetcard/index.php and see what that tells me. (Actually, I would guess that the entire /content/fleetcard/ folder is likely to hold additional hints for how to "fix" this.)